# Stackdriver {{$ctrl.errorGroupStats | crashErrorGroupTitle}}

Tags: google-compute-engine, stackdriver

This used to work fine earlier. Seems like an internal error at google side. I'm running some PHP code, any advise on formatting the errors?

[image: stackdriver error]

I've tried several ways to format errors:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you still seeing this? It looks like there was a bug that has been resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was fixed on google side.